# Edges in strongly connected digraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the minimum number of edges in a strongly connected digraph on $n$ vertices?
At first I thought it would be $n(n-1)$ but that is not the minimum number of edges. I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Comment: More context is needed. What did you try? Why did your answer fail?

Comment: A cyclic digraph with n-edges will do.

Comment: why did you think $n(n-2)$? that's all of the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum number is $n$, because you can create a cycle with them that connects all the $n$ vertices in one strongly-connected component.  With fewer than $n$ edges, you get at most a tree.